How to take backup specific tables in specific schemas in Postgresql via PgAdmin?
I try to backup my test database's 3 schemas and some important tables inside it.
For example:
schema a: t1,t2,t3
schema b: t5,t10
schema c: t15

There are also sequences, functions etc. ofc.
Taking whole db backup is easy from gui but when i try to backup choosing specific objects, it gives error while restoring because it can't find the schema itself. So i also need to be able to restore the schema.
How can i achieve this specific operation?

Pgadmin (GUI) calls the client application called pg_dump which supports picking specific database object(s).
